# Power Series for $\arcsin(x)$ and $\arcsin(x^2)$

Tags: integration, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I am having some trouble solving this question:

> Determine a power series entered at 0 for:
> $$f(x) = \arcsin(x^2)$$
> Hence, write an expression for the $kth$ derivative of $\arcsin(x)$, where $k \in \mathbb{N} $.

Side note:
I am able to derive the expression for the Maclaurin Series of $\arcsin(x)$, but I don't really understand how to use that information in obtaining the $kth$ derivative of $\arcsin(x)$.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550934/how-to-get-nth-derivative-of-arcsin-x

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208443/find-derivative-of-taylor-series) may be useful.

Comment: I don't really think either of these posts helps me. I am able to get the Maclaurin Expansion for $\arcsin(x^2)$, but I can't seem to relate it to the derivatives of $\arcsin(x)$.

Comment: Take or build the expansion of $\arcsin(y)$ and make $y=x^2$.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what I have to do now. Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

$$\arcsin(x) = x + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\left( {2k - 1} \right)!!}}{{\left( {2k} \right)!!}}\frac{{{x^{2k + 1}}}}{{2k + 1}}}$$
$$f(x)=\arcsin(x^2)=x + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\left( {2k - 1} \right)!!}}{{\left( {2k} \right)!!}}\frac{{{x^{4k + 2}}}}{{2k + 1}}}$$
for ease im going to say $s=\frac{d}{dx}$ and so:
$$sf(x)=1+\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\left( {2k - 1} \right)!!}}{{\left( {2k} \right)!!}}\frac{{{x^{4k + 1}}}}{{2k + 1}}}(4k+2)=1+2\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\left( {2k - 1} \right)!!}}{{\left( {2k} \right)!!}}{{x^{4k + 1}}}}$$
now:
$$s^2f(x)=2\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  (4k+1){\frac{{\left( {2k - 1} \right)!!}}{{\left( {2k} \right)!!}}{{x^{4k}}}}$$
now any higher derivates you can define in terms of a factorial